# How to Give multiple tab keypress in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have scenario is like, 
I have to write on multiple textbox which are in same grid and next to each-other.
But they don't have locator i have only one locator through which I can only type in first text box after i try by giving TAB key and type but fail...

find the image for more details.[image]

I am using selenium with java ..
[image]

Comment: Show your HTML and Code you tried.

Comment: Find the attached screenshot

Comment: Please post your code and html as text in the question

Comment: @DhavalAtri, I see no text input fields on provided image. Show exact `HTML` and code that fail to complete your task

Comment: Andression buddy thanks for reply..actually the input field is created as div tag :( soo i have to traverse many div tag and enter value

Comment: doing a search for qx-table-header-cell, I came across the qxwebdriver-java project at https://github.com/qooxdoo/qxwebdriver-java.  If the application under test is being developed using the qooxdoo framework, you might find it easier to use this webdriver to interact with that table.

Comment: You are right.
Application developed using the qooxdoo framework, but my friend now have to achieve this test scenario by tab .. So is there any way to do so..?